# I want the label from Multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

this is my array 
[image]

I want the output as Small, Medium , Large 
How to get it

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. It is important to **do your homework**. Tell us what you found and ***why*** it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 4):

```
$output = array();
foreach ($array as $el) $output[]= $el["label"];
print_r($output);
```

php 5.5+

```
$output = array_column($array, "label");
print_r($output);
```

Comment: isn't this from php 5.5

Comment: +1 for new information :) also good you update the answer

Answer (score 0):

To access the correct index just think of it as an array of arrays.

```
$options[0]['label']
$options[1]['label']
$options[2]['label']
```

Syntax may vary depending on what language you're using though. Why did you build an array you don't know how to access elements in...?

Answer (score 0):

I got my solutions

```
   $c= count($options);
for ( $i=0; $i < $c; $i++)
    { 
        echo $options[$i]['label'];
    }
```